# Building a DLL on Windows that uses a static /MT lib

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, msdn

I have a third-party static lib, libTA.lib. It was built with `/MT` and I can't change that. I want to link libTA into a DLL I'm building, mydll.{lib,dll}. Of course my dll should be built with `/MD`; my dll will be used with `/MD`-built exes (also not under my control). Linking mydll with libTA.lib fails (correctly, I'd say) due to *LNK2038, mismatch detected for RuntimeLibrary*.
So, what can I do about this? Building mydll with `/MT` seems like a terrible idea because I don't want to have multiple msvc runtimes.
So my question is, what are my options? Anyone been through this before and found a solution?

Comment: I just would go for `/MT` for the DLL. I don't see why it's so terrible to have one CRT in the EXE and another one in the DLL, provided that there is no new/delete malloc/free fopen/fwrite/fclose (AND ALL THE LIKES...) happening across the EXE/DLL boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep all the projects in your solution to /MD so that they will linked dynamically with external DLL libraries. The static libraries could be included in the additional dependencies or through #pragma include () directives. Note the DLL files should have their symbols exported through a .def file (use lib.exe to convert to lib file) or .lib file. However the toolset, target platform  settings of all the dynamic and static libraries should be same to avoid linker error.